# Изменить экран входящего вызова на Android

Tags: java, android, экран

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда на экране входящего вызова необходимо дополнительно показывать всего одну строку, которую мне отдаёт сервер, если этот номер есть в баз данных приложения которым пользуется юзер.

Из всей прочитанной мною инфы я узнал что для этого мне прийдётся переписать всю вьюху, но есть ещё один подводный камень. Вся инфа устарела, что я видел, ведь всё основывалось на WindowsManager, а с Android 6.0 разрешение `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` стало системным и простым приложениям его не заюзать. (У меня падало приложение с ошибкой, что нет разрешения на это)(Ну или я не нашёл как это обойти и другие способы).

Но ведь есть куча приложений меняющие входящие звонки? Как они реализованы?

Вот источники что я читал:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217179/replace-native-outgoing-call-screen-by-custom-screen-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401709/custom-incoming-outgoing-call-screen-in-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279520/adding-a-button-to-the-default-incoming-call-screen-in-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098545/how-to-modify-incoming-and-outgoing-call-screen-view-in-android

И многих других местах. [Этот пост](https://habrahabr.ru/company/skbkontur/blog/243063/) мне тоже не сильно помог. (не то что мне надо)

Всё что мне надо, так сделать [вот так](https://veloxy.helpshift.com/a/veloxy-for-salesforce-and-salesforce1-crm---emails-calendars-insights-contacts-opportunities-and-tasks/?s=getting-started&f=how-to-turn-on-veloxy-caller-id&l=en)

Comment: SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW? вы вообще не то делаете, вам активность нужна

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, Вы ушли далеко в другую сторону. Всё решение основывается на WindowsManager (наверно Вы видели пример с "плавающим" booble). Разрешение SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW без проблем запрашивается и ставится на 6.0.